# Bllim DataTables in Laravel 4 throws undefined getQuery() exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, datatables

I have the following simple controller:

```
class OrdersController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::all();

        return Datatables::of($orders)->make();
    }
}
```

Trying to use the bllim DataTables package to output my tables. When I can DataTables above, I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getQuery()
```

The error is located in `\Bllim\Datatables\Datatables.php` on the line:

```
$this->columns = $this->query_type == 'eloquent' ? $this->query->getQuery()->columns : $this->query->columns;
```

This method should be defined, unless I am mistaken. So what is missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Usage](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package)

> It is very simple to use this bundle. Just create your own fluent
>   query object or eloquent object without getting results (that means
>   **don't use get(), all()** or similar methods) and give it to Datatables. You are free to use all Eloquent ORM and Fluent Query
>   Builder features.

By calling the `all()` method you are returning an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object which in this case doesn't contain the `getQuery()` method, you need to pass a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` or `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instead.

Try this:

```
return Datatables::of(Order::select(array('id', 'othercolumns')))->make();
```

Or this:

```
$query = DB::table('orders')->select(array('id','othercolumns'));
return Datatables::of($query)->make();
```

Select the columns you want to show in the data table in the array.

Comment: Totally missed that. **face palm** Thanks!

Comment: It's kind of super natural @eComEvo :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha Seems you know a lot of Laravel Relationships. May you see my question? I can't find a solution. I have a similar problem to this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447389/how-to-get-a-builder-object-from-rows-related-to-pivot-laravel