# How to get a Builder object from rows related to pivot - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, datatables, eloquent, one-to-many

I'm trying to get all the "books" that one user have: but I can't do it how I need.

I use the following code:

```
/*Gets all books from the user whose id is 1*/     
$books= User::find(1)->books();
```

That return to me an `Collection` object; but I need a `Builder` object, as I get when I use the "select" method.

```
/* This code return me a "Builder" object */
Books::select(array('id', 'name', 'type'));
```

I need the `Builder` instead of `Collection` because I using Bllim/Datatables on my project and this package just accept a `Builder` object...

If I send it a `Collection` its throw me the next error (500 - Internal Server Error):

```
{
  "error":
   {
           "type":"ErrorException",
           "message":"Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::$columns",
           "file":"\/var\/www\/proyect\/myproyect\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php",
           "line":256
   }
}
```

Anybody knows the solution?

**EDIT:**

When I use the getQuery() method twice I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given","file":"\/var\/www\/proyect\/myproyect\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php","line":550}}
```

Is rare, because when I used the "select" method Datatables worked perfectly...

This code works:

```
Books::select(array('id', 'name', 'type'));
```

But the code you told me doesn't work:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->books()->getQuery()->getQuery();
```

Comment: Maybe exist any way to get all the books through a "select" method?

Comment: If you use `User::find(1)->books()`... notice the () it will allow you to query the result set.

Comment: Sorry, is a "typo" error. I have the "()" in my code: but throws me the error indicated on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method call `books()`:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->books(); // relation object
$user->books; // dynamic property
```

First `books()` returns a relation object, that you can chain `Eloquenr\Builder` or `Query Builder` methods on.

Second `books` is a dynamic property - the query is automatically executed and its result is stored in the `$user->relations['books']` and returned.

---

edit

As per comment - what you need is base `Query\Builder` object if you want to access `columns` property, so you need `getQuery` twice:

```
$user->books()
   ->getQuery() // get underlying Eloquent\Builder
   ->getQuery() // get underlying Query\Builder
   ->columns    // public property on the above
```

Comment: Jarek Tkaczyk, sorry, is a "typo" error. I have the "()" in my code: but throws me the error indicated on my question.

Comment: Thanks for all your time.